# receiving wm_copydata messages in delphi xe2 - unicode related

Tags: delphi, unicode, messaging

I have an application, written in Delphi, which I want to use to open files using the Windows "Open With" option.  I could do this perfectly happily in pre-Unicode Delphi versions; Windows puts the filename into a WM_copydata message, so I could fish it out using the CopyDataStruct record.  But in the Unicode world, this doesn't work; I only get half the filename in the lpdata buffer (followed by garbage).  When I examine the cbdata entry in the CopyDataStruct record, I find it contains the length of the filename, in numbers of characters (plus 1 for the terminator), not (as I would have thought it should) the number of bytes, which is of course now twice the number of characters. 
Note that it is not the case that my Delphi code is not reading the rest of the characters in the filename out of lpdata^ - I have looked in lpdata^, and they are not there. 
There are many examples on the web (including in StackOverflow) of how to avoid this issue if you are generating the WM_copydata message yourself; my problem is that I am not generating it, I am receiving it from Windows (64-bit Win7 or Win8).  Is there something that Delphi could be putting into the application, which I am not seeing, that is converting ANSI strings in lpdata to Unicode before I get at the WM_CopyData message?  And if so, how could I disable it (or make it correct the cbdata value)?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which application sends this message? I cannot imagine that this message is generated by Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The system isn't sending the `WM_COPYDATA` message. One of the apps is doing that. Very likely your own app!

You've probably got code that enforces a single instance. The second instance starts in response to the shell action. It detects an existing app and sends the `WM_COPYDATA` message. Then the second instance closes. The first instance receives the message and processes it.

The fact that the receiver is a Unicode aware app does not influence the content of the message. The sender determines its content. The system won't magically convert from 8 bit to 16 bit text. How could it? The content is opaque.

So, your next move is to find the code that sends the message and convert it to sending Unicode text.

Comment: David, you are absolutely right, I do have code enforcing the single instance.  I hadn't grasped that the message would be coming from that.  I will go back and see if I can sort it out on that basis, and post here if that is indeed the solution - but your suggestion makes a great deal of sense.  Many thanks.

Comment: It's clear that this is indeed the answer to your question